# Can I navigate my turtlebot3 on a map without lauching rviz? (Foxy-ROS2)

Tags: python, ros2

I am trying to navigate turtlebot on a map I created. I use these commands:

**ros2 topic pub --once /initialpose geometry_msgs/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped "{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: 'map'}, pose:{pose: {position: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}}}"**

**ros2 topic pub /goal_pose geometry_msgs/PoseStamped "{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: 'map2'}, pose: {position: {x: 2.53,y: 1.03, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 5.0, w: 1.0}}}"**

They work but only if I first run :

**ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py map:=/home/---/Desktop/Folder/map2.yaml**

I want to skip opening rviz in order to control the bot with a less powerful computer as rviz (I believe) will consume resource. Is there a way to skip rviz?

I tried these but nothing happeened:
**ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py map:=/home/---/Desktop/Folder/map2.yaml**

**ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server /home/---/Desktop/Folder/map2.yaml (then) ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py**

Neither worked. I get this error:

[planner_server-2] [INFO] [1680782755.903735844] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a (.launch) file that [launches rviz2](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/8237b796ea1571033bf3230fbc78d1143968ddd1/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py#L78) in it!

Launch files are used to run multiple nodes or commands in a single script. Usually, the launch files included in packages are used for reference and not meant for deployment.

I recommend you create a new (.launch) file based on [navigation2.launch.py](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/foxy-devel/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py). To run without rviz2 you just have to remove it from the script.

[The following lines get the rviz config file](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/8237b796ea1571033bf3230fbc78d1143968ddd1/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py#L49):

```
rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(
 ('nav2_bringup'),
 rviz',
 nav2_default_view.rviz)
```

[The following lines tell the script to run rviz2 with 'rviz_config_dir'](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/8237b796ea1571033bf3230fbc78d1143968ddd1/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py#L78):

```
Node(
 package='rviz2',
 executable='rviz2',
 name='rviz2',
 arguments=['-d', rviz_config_dir],
 parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
 output='screen'),
```

If you just remove this last one, that will do the trick!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Didn't try it yet, but I believe it will work.